# Use android phone with broken screen as WiFi camera

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, cyanogenmod, adb, camera, vnc

The screen of my android phone is broken and since I couldn't find a replacement screen I thought of using the phone as wifi camera. I've installed IP cam and use the android.screencast to control and setup the device using USB cable.

However, the color depth of the screen is extremely low with color banding and all this like if it has only something like 8-bit color depth. I have another phone of the same brand available and tried the same steps on that phone and it works with high color depth.

I blieve that due to the missing screen android might fall back to a default color depth as it cannot probe the screen as to which color depths is available. Unfortunately this means that basically my nice idea is useless as the quality of this IP camera is terrible and useless.

Does anyone has an idea of how to change the color depth so that I can continue to use the phone for the described purpose?

Comment: Just as a follow up on the issue: it seems that apart from the camera the rest of the system has a high bit-per-pixel number (don't know which number but something like 16bit or more). Just when I open the camera I see heavy color banding. The funny thing is that I took a picture, uploaded it my computer and it has the color banding on my computer screen as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the camera isn't damaged as well?  IP Webcam has settings for resolution and quality, but I don't see anything indicating that it's tied to the screen of the device.

Actually, I'm not sure we're using the same cam app.  Maybe it would help to try a different one.  I used 'IP Webcam' because I was using mine for video.  I'm sure there are good options for still shots.

You can also try using something like TinyCam Monitor (free) to view the stream if you're viewing live video.  It makes for an easy security camera system.