# Broken screen/glass, turned off, pc-controll? HELP?

Tags: screen, touchscreen, broken-screen

I was wondering if there is any ways for me to controll my phone (Sony Xperia V) with my computer?
Half of the glass/screen is broken, so i cant write anything on the lower part of the screen! The phone is not rooted, and has also been turned off, so im kinda stuck.

So, my question is:
Is there any ways for me to controll my non-rooted, turned off, screenbroken phone with my computer?

Cheers!

Comment: Will it boot at all? Is it a spider crack in the glass or did you like run it over with a car?

Comment: Please see [My screen got broken, how to see on the computer what I'm doing in my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36860/16575). And as for @John: [Use android phone with broken screen as WiFi camera](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16842/16575). Furthermore: [Control Android with broken screen from PC](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42105/16575), and [several more](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=broken+screen+answers%3A1).

Comment: @Izzy I was trying to gauge whether or not the internals had been affected.

Comment: Yeah, sorry @John: I should have gone to bed (2am it was!) Didn't read your comment correctly, my apologies.

Comment: No harm done @Izzy, It's 2AM where I am now so I know how you felt! Haha cheers! Great links by the way, I have a few phones with cracked screens that I might go dig out myself and find some use for them.

Comment: Ha! So at 2am intuition kicks in, and my hinting at you proved correct nevertheless? *LOL* So I'm glad my mistake turned into a fortune at last :D

Comment: I got a spidercrack from near the bottomw left corner and over to the other side, only 50% of the screen, and no internals has been affected.

Comment: only thing is that the broken glass does that the touch wont work on the lower part of the screen

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would try to get control over the device using [ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/is-there-a-minimal-installation-of-adb). From there you can get your files back and root the device if you want. Also as Izzy suggested in the comments, there are several applications for a device with a cracked or unusable screen. Android is Linux based, so Android can do almost anything a Linux based server can do. You can find a lot of great server based applications for android by searching on Google.

Remember, Android is a Linux based operating system, so Android can do almost anything a Linux based server can do. A lot of server applications are going to require root.

It also seems your question can best be answered by: [Control android with broken screen from pc](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42105/control-android-with-broken-screen-from-pc)

Comment: +1 from me to that. Just one handicap: While ADB gives great power to the user (I wouldn't know any more how to do without that), it requires *USB Debugging* on the device to be turned on. If that wasn't done before the cracker, and no trick (e.g. NFC tag) prepared to switch it on without touching the screen, OP might be in bad luck. Still, the other linked questions might provide some hints how it still can be achieved.

Comment: @Izzy ah yes, I suppose USB Debugging would have to have been turned on before the screen got cracked. Good point.

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
I dont remember if the USB Debugging was on or off! :S
I've been trying ADB and some other things, but I dont think did it right, cause it wounldnt work. Im also kinda scared of rooting the phone cause I dont know what that will do about example; waranty, or what it would do to my phone, or if its worth it?

Comment: I've got ADB/SDK and Droid@screen and/also and emulator that came with the SDK download, but.. I have NOO idea of what I'm doing! :S

Comment: Do you care if you void the warranty? Or are you going to try to get a new one through warranty?

Comment: I dont think I will get a new one through warranty, but I read some place that rooting could "block" the phone if you did it wrong?

Comment: Hmm.. what Im trying to say is that i dont know much about rooting, what it will cause, how to do it, or if its worth it!
Or how to use ADB

Comment: How do I turn on the USB Debugging?

Comment: Ive done all this steps, but i dont find my device here

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=QMbvdB4_DVo

Comment: Before you do anything else I would recommend just trying to get a new one through warrenty

Comment: Okay, I dont think I will, last time I had a phone with problems I had to send it in within the very first week to get a new one. And if I send it in to were i bought it to repair, it will cost over 3.000,- NOK. :(
I'll try see if anyone can fix it for less!

Anyways, thanks for your time and help!