# Turn a Android Phone with broken screen into dedicated Web server

Tags: root-access, linux, remote-access, web-server, broken-screen

I have a Nexus 4 with a broken LCD/Digitizer, I have no control via touch at all. The other parts of the phone are functional.
Now, what I want to do and hope is possible is to clear the phone and install some Linux distro via Usb. The trick is, I need to be able to control the installation via wifi or USB directly after the upload of the Linux package. After this I want to run it as a dedicated Web server of some sort. I welcome any type of solutions. All I want in the end is to use my phone as a dedicated Web Server which I can control remotely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Majk! We support end-users with Android-specific issues, but cannot help you setting up a Linux server on a device, though it *was* running Android before. Still, some helpful hints:

- There are means to control your device even with a broken screen. We've got several issues reported where people wanted to do exactly that. Please check e.g.:

  - [My screen got broken, how to see on the computer what I'm doing in my device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/36860/16575)
  - [Control Android with broken screen from PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42105/16575)
  - [Use android phone with broken screen as WiFi camera](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16842/16575)
  - [Broken Screen + Using adb shell to run vnc server](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19317/16575)
- There are several web server apps available for Android as well. Even some supporting/including things like PHP and MySQL. Some examples:

  - [AndroPHP](http://www.appbrain.com/app/AndroPHP/com.ayansoft.androphp)
  - [Ulti Server: PHP, MySQL, PMA](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Ulti-Server-PHP-MySQL-PMA/com.icecoldapps.ultiserver)
  - [KSWEB: server + PHP + MySQL](http://www.appbrain.com/app/KSWEB-server-PHP-MySQL/ru.kslabs.ksweb)
  - [NAMP nginx android web server](http://www.appbrain.com/app/NAMP-nginx-android-web-server/ru.nampltd.namp)

I guess that should get you started if you want to solve your issue using Android. And as I initially wrote: Doing that with any other OS, even on an "Android device", is beyond the scope of this site. But I would wonder if you will really need that, after these details – right? :)