# HTTP servers with scripting support on Android

Tags: web-server

I'm looking to host simple web apps on my smartphone in a group (like a LAN party, just not as hardcore).
Because of both lack of portability and lack of specific programming skills, I can't just develop a client app to play. Therefore, I need a server - preferably an HTTP one - which can serve dynamic content. I already found many servers to host static files, and I also found a few servers supporting PHP as a scripting language, but I couldn't find any app that did all these things at once:

- Be a server, i.e. support connections from the local network;
- Serve dynamic content, i.e. parse and execute scripts which I can edit;
- Is free for personal use.

Comment: Wow. I'd be **very** surprised if you found a php server that runs on Android. \*googles\* OKAY LET ME [GET MY FOOT OUT OF MY MOUTH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andi.serverweb&hl=en). >_>

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/58849/16575) for multiple candidates supporting PHP+MySQL and more.

Comment: @Izzy I found a decent server from the answer you linked. You might want to post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Very interesting, now, can you go one step further and use noip, to point to your smartphone's IP address and hit on your blog? (Am sure WP can be hacked to run off the sdcard?) then... profit? \o/ :)

Comment: @t0mm13b see [my answer below](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/62816/16575) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**AndroPHP**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ayansoft.androphp&hl=en) looks like it'll fill your needs quite nicely.

You can...

- Deply dynamic PHP content
- Serve pages over LAN
- Use a MySQL Database

Heck, this'd be awesome for all *sorts* of events. Have people whip out their phones, navigate to your locally hosted signup form, etc, then export the mysql tables out later.

Comment: Neither satisfy the requirement, "is free for personal use" - one has a trial period and the other one is paid.

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello Ah, I didn't realize that the first one was only a trial. I've updated the answer with one that seems to be real freeware.

Comment: I'm testing AndroPHP right now.

Comment: I swear this is so amazing. Brace yourselves, LAN parties are incoming.

Answer (score 3):

That unfortunately needs some 3<sup>rd</sup> party app, as there's no "native" feature included with Android. Apps you might wish to check for this purpose include:

- [AndroPHP](http://www.appbrain.com/app/AndroPHP/com.ayansoft.androphp) (already [described by dotVezz](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/62805/16575))
- [Ulti Server: PHP, MySQL, PMA](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Ulti-Server-PHP-MySQL-PMA/com.icecoldapps.ultiserver) includes DyDNS, FTP, FTPS, SFTP, SSH, PHP, MySQL (which also answers t0mm13b's comment)
- [KSWEB: server + PHP + MySQL](http://www.appbrain.com/app/KSWEB-server-PHP-MySQL/ru.kslabs.ksweb) also includes FTP and some administrative tools and a function to update external IP in No-IP service (second answer to t0mm13b, even with his favorite "no-ip")
- [NAMP nginx android web server](http://www.appbrain.com/app/NAMP-nginx-android-web-server/ru.nampltd.namp) with PHP, MySQL and FTP

Comment: upvote for you sir! :D \o/

Comment: All of these except AndroPHP look like trialware (is that a word?).

Comment: @trysis So you can find out if they fit your needs, and then buy the full version. Anything wrong with that? ;)

Comment: No, it's just the OP said he only wanted free versions and someone already called out the other answerer for including free versions. The OP didn't say anything about trials, though.

Comment: Right. That's why my answer has one free candidate (to fulfill the request); think of the others as "something to consider as well". If they offer significant improvements, they might be worth the money. And after all, this answer is not just for the one who asked – for others, the "free" part might be a "nice-to-have", as they care more for the problem to be solved ;)